# when i use mobx with react-router here is a warning

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Warning: Provider: It is not recommended to assign props directly to state because updates to props won't be reflected in state. In most cases, it is better to use props directly.

here is the router.js

```
const router = () => {
return (
        <Provider {...stores}>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
  )
}

export default router;
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  render () {
     return (
        <div>
            <TodoList />
        </div>
     )
   }
 }

 export default Home
```

TodoList.js

```
@inject('todoStore')
@observer
class TodoList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render () {
        const name = this.props.todoStore;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{name}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

here is code

Comment: Please share some code snippet, where you assign props to state

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code as Michael mentioned so that we can understand your issue well and suggest possible solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a complain from **React** `16.5.0`. And looks like this is something `mobx-react` need to solve. Here you can read more about that: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/545

Answer (score 0):

Assign your props like below and call them wherever required

```
render () {
    const { todoStore } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{todoStore}</span>
        </div>
    )
 }
```